# ctypes.get_last_error doesn't work but Win32 API call works

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, ctypes, getlasterror

```py
import ctypes
import platform
import queue
import threading
from typing import Union

class Runner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(
        self,
        exc: queue.Queue,
        que: queue.Queue,
        args: list[list[str]],
        call_conv: str,
        returns: str,
        lib_path: str,
        name_or_ord: str,
        get_last_error: tk.IntVar,
        show_get_last_error: bool,
        errno: tk.IntVar,
        show_errno: bool,
    ) -> None:
        self.__exc = exc
        self.__queue = que
        self.__get_last_error = get_last_error
        self.__show_get_last_error = show_get_last_error
        self.__errno = errno
        self.__show_errno = show_errno
        self.__is_windows = platform.system() == "Windows"
        self.__call_conv = CallConvention(call_conv)
        self.__restype = ParameterType(returns).ctype
        if self.__call_conv == CallConvention.StdCall:
            self.__handle = ctypes.WinDLL(
                lib_path,
                use_last_error=show_get_last_error,
                use_errno=show_errno,
            )
            self.__functype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE
        else:
            if self.__is_windows:
                self.__handle = ctypes.CDLL(
                    lib_path,
                    use_errno=show_errno,
                    use_last_error=show_get_last_error,
                )  # type: ignore
            else:
                self.__handle = ctypes.CDLL(
                    lib_path,
                    use_errno=show_errno,
                )  # type: ignore
            self.__functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE
        if name_or_ord.startswith("@"):
            self.__name_or_ord = int(name_or_ord[1:])  # type: Union[str, int]
        else:
            self.__name_or_ord = name_or_ord
        self.__argtypes = []
        self.__argvalues = []
        for arg in args:
            type_, value = arg
            argtype = ParameterType(type_).ctype
            argvalue = Marshaller.str2ctype(argtype, value)
            self.__argtypes.append(argtype)
            self.__argvalues.append(argvalue)
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        try:
            if self.__argtypes:
                prototype = self.__functype(self.__restype, *self.__argtypes)
            else:
                prototype = self.__functype(self.__restype)
            ptr = prototype((self.__name_or_ord, self.__handle))
            result = ptr(*self.__argvalues)
            run_result = RunResult(result, self.__argvalues)
        except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
            self.__exc.put(e)
        else:
            self.__queue.put(run_result)
        # This is thread safe, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352087
        if self.__show_get_last_error and self.__is_windows:
            # ! ctypes.get_last_error() doesn't work
            gle = int(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
            log.debug("GetLastError - %d", gle)
            self.__get_last_error.set(gle)
        if self.__show_errno:
            errno = ctypes.get_errno()
            log.debug("errno - %d", errno)
            self.__errno.set(errno)
```

`ThreadRunner` executes a function from a library and runs in its own thread.

`le` is thread-safe despite what many people think!

In the `run` method, I execute a Win32 API function `LoadLibraryA` which throws error 126 when its unsuccessful. I also construct `WinDLL` with `use_last_error=True`.

However, in `run` method, this:

```py
ctypes.get_last_error()
```

**doesn't** work, this **works**:

```py
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
```

I don't understand why this happens, the ctypes docs say that it is a private `ctypes` copy limited to the thread, but so is `GetLastError`; its limited to a thread.

I can say for sure that the `tk.IntVar` doesn't cause any problems related to thread safety, as it comes from the main (UI) thread.

I *think* a similar problem occurs with `ctypes.get_errrno()` also.

Comment: FWIW I think I have seen this before. Have you submitted a bug report, or looked for one in case it has been addressed already.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  I used simple Python threads in a small example and it works correctly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't seen this before.

Comment: @MarkTolonen It will work because you must have set the last error using ctypes, I execute LoadLibrary to get that value. I will @ you once I upload this code on Github

Comment: No I executed LoadLibrary in different threads and successfully got the error code from unsuccessful loads. Don’t give a link to code, update your question with a [mcve]

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can't and it would not be any more useful than what you did, the code I use does. The problem is with the differences in how `ctypes.get_last_error` works vs. how `GetLastError` works. I have posted the complete class.

Comment: A [mcve] will show *how* to use the class to produce the problem you see. Better yet, hard-code the final result the causes the problem so it isn't long and incomprehensible.  That's how you debug a problem like this.  I'm not doing that part for you.  Reduce it to a concrete example. The code should be executable by cut/paste/run no changes.